# String used in recv() does not printf as it should

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to write a server-client program for practice but I'm having trouble with the the string I use in the recv() function.

```
void *recieve_handler(void *socket_desc){
int client_sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
int data_len;
char client_message[BUFFER_SIZE];

data_len = 1;

while (data_len > 0){
    data_len = recv(client_sock, client_message, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
    client_message[data_len-1] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", client_message);
    printf("ME:");
}
close(client_sock);

}
```

I would like after I receive the string from the client to print it and then print a label in the next line.
The problem is whatever I try,I keep getting this outcome:

```
"1st message from client"
[buffer]
```

and then when the client sends another message it prints along with me ME: label in front of it.

```
ME: "2nd message from client"
```

I need to have the label printed with the 1st message.

Comment: To start with, if the recv() returns with data_len=BUFFER_SIZE, (ie buffer is completely filled), 'client_message[data_len-1] = '\0';' overwrites the last char:(

Comment: And don't forget to check the return value of `recv()` for error **before** using `client_message`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to flush the stdout fflush(stdout); after printing ME:

e.g.

```
printf("%s\n", client_message);
printf("ME:");
fflush(stdout);
```